# Hiding then showing the dropdown arrow in jquery from a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can hide the dropdown arrow in a select element with this css!
But I want to hide and more importantly show it in jquery?

```css
select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        text-indent: 1px;
        text-overflow: '';
    }
```

```html
<select style="border: 0px;">
  <option value="0">Test1</option>
  <option value="1">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: _"show it in jquery"_ ? What is that ?

Comment: Put `CSS` in `CSS` frame...Not in `JS`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom css class that hides the drop down arrow and use jquery to toggle that class on the select element.

For your needs you may need to use the jquery methods addClass and removeClass instead of toggleClass.

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('#select').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        text-indent: 1px;
        text-overflow: '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
<select id="select" style="border: 0px;" disabled>
  <option value="0">Test1</option>
  <option value="1">Test2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A less complex way is to use a pseudo-element and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Test1</option>
    <option value="1">Test2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 4px 18px 4px 6px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
.dropdown:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: 14px;
  bottom: 1px;
  color: transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid;
  border-left: 4px solid;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here, the `pointer-events: none;` makes it so that clicking on the pseudo-element passes through to the `select`. You can hide and show it with `:hover` or `:focus`, or add a class with jQuery:

CSS:

```
.dropdown.hide-arrow:after { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.dropdown').toggleClass('hide-arrow')
```